# blank.html is downloaded multiple times

Tags: gwt, https

GWT is used and the application is deployed on WebLogic using HTTPS.

The performance is poor and with F12 Developer Tools, we could see that blank.html is downloaded multiple times. This is clearly related to GWT but we have not been able to figure out why.

The following is from javascript:

```
defineSeed(2613, 2614, makeCastMap([Q$BaseModelData, Q$ModelData, Q$Theme, Q$Serializable]), Slate_0);
var SLATE;
function $clinit_GXT(){
    $clinit_GXT = nullMethod;
    IMAGES = new XImages_generatedBundle_0;
    MESSAGES = new XMessages__0;
    SSL_SECURE_URL = getModuleBaseURL() + 'blank.html';
}
```

This is from GWT.java:

```
/**
 * URL to a blank file used by GXT when in secure mode for iframe src to
 * prevent the IE insecure content. Default value is 'blank.html'.
 */
public static String SSL_SECURE_URL = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "blank.html";
```

Does anyone know under what circumstances blank.html is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> This is from GWT.java:

This is actually from GXT.java.

This is used in a few cases when creating an `<iframe>` element, so that IE won't give errors if your site is hosted from SSL. I can actually only find one case (as of GXT 3.1.1) which uses this, in `Layer.java`. Only IE pages loaded from `https` urls will make use of this.

The Layer class uses this as a "shim", a way to prop up some DOM elements above overs, and work around some browser bugs (typically plugin or iframe related). Menus and popup dialogs use this to ensure that they don't appear "underneath" content that they should be "above".

This file is very small - just enough HTML to convince IE than the iframe has correctly loaded, and no more. It never changes, and should load nearly instantly.

As far as performance goes, this should only happen when a Menu or Window/Dialog/Tooltip is shown - these shouldn't be happening on app startup usually, at least not more than a window or two. Additionally, the browser should recognize that it is loading the same element and cache it correctly, and not load it multiple times (though it might be listed several times as hitting the cache). If the server has instructed the browser to never cache the file, that is something you should look at changing.

In short, this is very unlikely to be the cause of *any* performance issues, at least in GXT itself. If somehow you have the shim enabled on every single widget in your project, this should not be required. If the file is loading slowly, something may be very wrong with your server configuration.

For reference, here is the entire file:

```
<html></html>
```